# Files Transform : EPERM: operation not permitted in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, autodeploy

I am trying to make Release in Azure DevOps for .Net Core Web Application.

I am using the **File Transform** task of Release. for Dev environment it's working perfectly fine. but when I am trying to make release defination for Test it's giving me error that  ##[error]Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat '\(ServerName)\d$\www(sitename)'

[image]

Any one have idea about that?

Comment: Does the account you're running the release from have permissions in the Test environment along with Dev?

Comment: @m00nbeam360.0 yeah it completed all other steps like copying files etc successfully on Test

Answer (score 0):

buddy!
I just had the same issue today. The solution was to add the service account that the agent runs as to the admin group on the machine.
However, I think this is only necessary, if you're accessing the files via a network path.
The confusing part was that all the files gave permission to the agent service account, but the accessing of the server via a network path caused the problem.